# What does new applied to an interface mean?

Tags: go

I understand that if `T` is a struct, then this amounts to creating an empty struct (sensible empty values)::

```
t := new(T)
```

However, given the following snippet::

```
type Burper interface {burp() int}       

b := new(Burper)
```

What is created & what is the usefulness of new'ing an interface ?

Comment: It seems to return nil.

Comment: @FUZxxl Not in my case. `fmt.Println(new(Burper))` prints an address (as new returns a pointer).

Comment: Yes, it returns a pointer to nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This just creates a pointer to a Burper (which is an interface). As there is (almost) no sensible use for a pointer to an interface this is valid Go, harmless and useless in practice.

`b` is a pointer and points to the zero value of Burper which is nil.

See http://play.golang.org/p/r6h8KiA9pa

Comment: And here is one use case for  an interface-typed nil-pointer: https://github.com/codegangsta/inject/blob/master/inject.go#L146